# Huawei push kit message not received from clevertap push console

Tags: push-notification, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification, huawei-mobile-services

Here we integrate clevertap sdk as below, somehow HMS push kit msg is not received:

```
<service
   android:name="com.panda.demo.HmsPushService"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.huawei.push.action.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>

implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.8.2'


public class HmsPushService extends HmsMessageService {

    private static final String TAG = "pushdemo";
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.i(TAG, "receive token:" + token);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to integrate CleverTap SDK for Huawei as mentioned [here](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/clevertap-huawei-push-integration).

For latest Push Kit versions, please refer to Huawei Push Kit documentation [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050040072):

1. Library version is wrong, 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:4.0.0' , check [here](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/android-quickstart-guide)
2. Remove "service" from manifest, you will receive msg

   a. If you choose to have the "service" , the HmsPushService Class can not be empty like this. It should have at least more code like the sample in
   **github**:    `onMessageReceived()` 
   which call
   `CleverTapAPI.createNotification(getApplicationContext(),extras)`

   b. add more code in this class to handle push, data, in-app

If above steps do not work, please provide further details per your case.

Comment: nice steps and documents to follow, and it works after using this solution.